# Trying to access the options of a dropdown box using jQuery/javascript, but it's saying that .options is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a dropdown box dynamically in jQuery by appending html as follows:

```
.append("<br><SELECT  NAME='Month_list' class='month_selection'</SELECT>");
```

It gets created fine, but I'm trying to dynamically add options to it using the following code:

```
$('.month_selection:last').options.add(new Option(month_array[index]));
```

but I'm getting the following error in Firebug:

```
$(".month_selection:last").options is undefined
```

The selector is working fine, because I can run the line of code `$(".month_selection:last").remove()` and the dropdown box gets removed, and from what I can tell from various tutes `.options` is how to access the options, so what am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the `<select>` DOM element to access [`.options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select) like this:

```
$('.month_selection:last')[0].options
//or...
$('.month_selection').get(-1).options
```

[You an give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bhCTY/).

For DOM properties you need to get the DOM element you care about first (via `[0]` or [`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) in this case) *then* access its properties, otherwise you're trying to access properties on the jQuery object which don't exist.